# Dataframe pairwise multiplication in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix-multiplication

If I have these data

```
data = {'f1':['A','B','B','A'],'f2':['X','Y','Z','Z']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
feat_1 = pd.get_dummies(df['f1'])
feat_2 = pd.get_dummies(df['f2'])
```

What is a short way to do this multiplication between feat_1 and feat_2 in pandas?

feat_1

```
   A  B
0  1  0
1  0  1
2  0  1
3  1  0
```

feat_2

```
   X  Y  Z
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
3  0  0  1
```

Desired result: feat_1 * feat_2

```
   AX  AY  AZ  BX  BY  BZ
0   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   1   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   1
3   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

Comment: Can you post a desired output that isn't an image?

Comment: I understand now. Thanks. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

By using `reindex` after `get_dummies`

```
col=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.f1.unique(),df.f2.unique()]).map(''.join) 


df.apply(''.join,1).str.get_dummies().reindex(columns=col,fill_value=0)
Out[605]: 
   AX  AY  AZ  BX  BY  BZ
0   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   1   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   1
3   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

Comment: This is just was I was trying to do. Perhaps there's no shorter way then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using categories:

```
from itertools import product

cats = map(''.join, product(df['f1'].unique(), df['f2'].unique()))
cdt = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(cats)
result = pd.get_dummies(df.sum(axis=1).astype(cdt))
```

Which produces the desired result:

```
   AX  AY  AZ  BX  BY  BZ
0   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   1   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   1
3   0   0   1   0   0   0
```